# What value of n makes the span of vectors equal to R3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, span

Im asked the question what **values** of $n$ makes

$$
span\begin{pmatrix} {\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\n \end{bmatrix}} \end{pmatrix} = \mathbb{R}^3
$$

What I did is:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1&|&b_{1} \\ 0&1&1&|&b_{2} \\ 1&0&n&|&b_{3} \end{bmatrix}
\\
$$
So when I solve I get:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&|&b_{1}-b_{2} \\ 0&1&1&|&b_{2} \\ 0&0&n&|&b_{3}+b_{2}-b_{1} \end{bmatrix}
$$
So that $n=b_{3}+b_{2}-b_{1}$
Is this correct or am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're not completely wrong, but you're making it unnecessary complicated.

You have $3$ vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3\in\mathbb R^3$. As $\dim(\mathbb R^3)=3$ we have: $$\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2,v_3)=\mathbb R^3 \iff v_1,v_2,v_3~\text{are linearly independent}.$$

To check for which $n\in\mathbb N$ these vectors are linearly independent the easiest way would involve calculating the determinant of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & v_3\end{pmatrix}$...can you take it from here?

Comment: Im sorry I havent learned what determinants are yet.

Comment: Ok...then you'll have to work with a system of linear equations, but it will still be easier. Recall the definition of linear independence: $$v_1,\ldots v_n~\text{are linearly independent} \iff a_1v_1+\ldots a_nv_n=0~\text{holds  only for}~a_1=\ldots=a_n=0.$$ Thus you only have to look at $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & n & 0 \end{array}\right).$$ For what value of $n$ does this system of linear equations have only one solution?

Comment: n=1 would only have one solution?

Comment: That's one possible value for $n$, but there are more.

Comment: Wouldn't any value for n only have one solution?

Comment: Are you guessing or is this based on your calculations? No, there is at least one value for $n$ where we don't have only one solution, hence those vectors won't be a basis for $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Im guessing, not quite sure how you calculate all n with only 1 solution

Comment: You should get to $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & n & 0 \end{array}\right),$$ so far everything clear? Now, the third row is the one, thats important. Written as an equation this reads as: $$n\cdot a_3=0.$$ We want, that this **only** holds, if $a_3=0$. But for which value of $n$ will this equation always be true regardless of the value that $a_3$ takes?

Comment: Why is that you make the system equal to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Solving system of linear equations 
\begin{align}
a_1 +a_2+a_3&=0\\
a_2+a_3&=0\\
a_1+a_3n&=0
\end{align}
indicates that $a_1=0, a_2=-a_3$ and $a_3n=0$. Third equality imply that all $n \neq 0$ will make the given vectors L.I.